# Getting products information, in woocommerce based on products ID

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have some ids like this

```
$products = (1,2,3,4);
```

I need to query woocommerce database to get info all products with that ids something like when im querying based on cateogory

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
    'category' => array('Test'),
));
```

Is possible to get based on ID, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the [`WC_Product`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-Data-Schema) object for a product ID with the `wc_get_product()` function. So by using `array_map()` you can get the product data for those IDs like this:

```
$product_ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
$products    = array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product_ids );

foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    echo $product->get_name();
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_name() on boolean

Comment: The problem is when one product id does not exist

Comment: So check that the product exists before doing anything `if ( $product )`